# Segue from custom UITableViewCell on Master View of UISplitViewController to open Detail View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller

I added a custom `UITableViewCell`s created on a .xib file to Master Table View Controller from my `UISplitViewController` on my Storyboard.

When I tap a cell, the Detail View doesn't show anything.

I'm using Xcode 6 developing an Universal project. I'm doing that:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Detail Segue" sender:indexPath];
}
```

This code works on an iPhone devices but when I run the project on an iPad this doesn't work.

How can I add a segue to show my Detail View from Master Table View Controller using custom `UITableViewCell`s ?